# jFlex methods (yypushStream,yypopStream..) trigger "cannot find symbol" error in user code

Tags: jflex

I have some user code in jFlex that generates a BufferedReader from yytext(), then has it pushed into the stream stack.

However, it seems that yypushStream(), yypopStream(), yymoreStreams()  methods are not recognized by javac and trigger a "cannot find symbol" error whenever those methods are called from within the user code.

For instance:

```
public void toStream(String a){

InputStream fstream= new ByteArrayInputStream(a.getBytes());
BufferedReader freader = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(fstream));
yypushStream(freader);

    }
```

Returns the following output:

```
symbol: method yypushStream(BufferedReader)
Yylex.java:389: error: cannot find symbol
yypushStream(freader);
^
```

I've also tried `Yylex.yyPopStream();` and `%public` to no effect.

Is it that those methos cannot be used in the user code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read carefully [Jflex Manual](http://www.jflex.de/manual.html), it is written that the methods `yyPushStream()`, `yyPopStream()` and `yyMoreStreams()` are available only in the skeleton file called `skeleton.nested`, that you find in the src folder.
So you shouldn't use it or call it in the user code.

Comment: The thing is there has to be a way to use it. Otherwise, why include them in the manual alongside with other methods such as yypushback?

Comment: Let me understand one thing:  are the element you have to scan present in a file? If yes, why don't you open it and you scan it directly with Jflex?

Comment: I wanted JFlex to split the file in two, being the first half 140 characters long and process them separately with different sets of rules. In the end, I had to process the file as a whole and keep count of characters so I knew when 140 characters had been reached.

Comment: Why don't you think that the splitting in two files could be made by your program and then each file should be processed one at the time by Jflex? I think this could be more simple for you and lets you use JFlex normally, instead of methods like yyMoreStreams() or similar...

Comment: I was required to write a .flex specification in order to produce a standalone analyzer. Any custom code had to by inside the .flex file.

Comment: Sorry for the delay of my comment. Anyway I think that in the user code you could declare a class that let you split the file in two parts and then you will process separately.